# Removing the default text ">" from the command palette in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I open up the command palette in VSCode by pressing `Command + Shift + P`, I'm greeted with the following menu:

[image: VSCode Command Palette]

This is great and all, but the input isn't empty, it contains a `>`. I don't really use the `>` for running tasks (I have custom tasks setup) or opening files. It's annoying that I constantly have to press `Command + Shift + P`, wait for it to load, and then press `Backspace` before doing anything.

I guess that I'm missing something major, because I don't see why the `>` is included by default. The [official page](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface) doesn't mention the use of `>` either.

So, I have 3 questions:

1. What does the `>` do in the command palette in VSCode?
2. Is there any way to remove the default input (`>`) from the command palette?
3. If removing the `>` isn't supported right now, could I write a VSCode extension to remove the `>`?

If there's a better place to ask, please let me know!

Comment: What do you use the command palette for, then? If your purpose is only to open file, you can use `Command + P` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** the `>` is meant to specify some settings that belongs to the idle. If you open that line (`Command + shift + P`) and type "settings", you can see a list of things, that are configurations needed to VScode in order to do some stuff. IE: `settings.json` have some idle config and you can add settings for some extension.

**2/3.** I believe it's useless since you can just do `Command + P` and use this function that search the names of your files into your project.

Anyway I think stackExange would've been a better place to post. But maybe some user will find this question helpful.

**Edit**

Have a look here: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings

I believe you can unbind that particular action (`Command + Shift + P`) if you want, instead of making an extension to VSCode. This might answer your point nr. **3**

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't realize that I could just use `Command + P` to open the prompt without placeholder text. Thanks so much!

Comment: @LiRa Maybe I've found out how to remove it. Have a look at the edit!

Comment: There are a number of things that the quickOpen panel can do.  If you Do Ctrl+P and type "?" you will see the various options, like ">" to show commands and ":" go to a line number, etc.  For many of these there are separate keybindings, like Ctrl+G which just opens the quick open panel with ":" preinserted, like Ctrl+Shift+P preinserts the ">".

Answer (score 2):

The `>` prefix is actually what allows you to search files from the *Command Palette* or, in general, switch context from the different tools. The meaning is as follows:

- No prefix: Go to File
- `>`: Run Command
- `:`: Go to Line
- `@`: Go to Symbol in File
- `@:`: Go to Symbol in File by Category
- `#`: Go to Symbol in Workspace

… plus some other commands (use `?` to get a list).

You can still open all these tools directly (from the corresponding menu items or using the appropriate short-cuts) but you also have the option of removing the prefix and typing a different one, e.g., if you realise you've being typing in the wrong tool. This is similar to the way in which you can typically switch between *Find* and *Replace* in this and other editors.